# PHP - unlink('file_name') not working

Tags: php, file-permissions, delete-file, unlink

I have issues while trying to delete files in PHP, using `unlink('filename')`.
I have tried with a complexe file and it didn't worked. I've been using relative paths as adviced on other post about this.

So i've made the simpliest script possible :

```
<?php
unlink("acs.gif");
?>
```

The script is located in the same folder as my `asc.gif` is, tho it still doesn't work. 
I've got no fatal errors, and a warning when enabling `error_reporting()` and `init_set()`. But the file is still there.

I've tried to set the permissions to both my folder, my image and my script to `0777` but it didn't help.

I'm getting quite confused about what is happening.

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Comment: Is the result of calling `unlink` true or false?

Comment: Actually, `false`. I've tried it again right now and it seems it is not able to find the file.. Weird.

Comment: try using full path <?php
unlink("localhost/projects/image/acs.gif"); // try this type
?>

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Now telling me that `Warning: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking`

Comment: Use full local path.  Eg `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: @Akintunde This worked fine ! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use absulte filepaths. In case you want to delete a file which is in the same directory of the called script, poleteaw answer should work (besides the missing / in the path):

```
unlink(__DIR__ . '/' . $filename);
```

Nevertheless take look of php's directory function [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and the [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

So what if you want to delete a file which is not inside your directory:

1. You can use the realpath() method to generate an absolute path out of a relative path. So realpath('/one/two/three/../..') results in '/one' - or for your case you can do something like `realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../')` to get into the root directory of you project.
2. The recommended way is to use a variable which holds the absolute path to the directory where you want to store and administrate your files like `$filesDir = '/path/to/my/files'`. With this approach you have two wins: your users files do not reside in your php project files and you have a way much better overview of which files are uploaded/administrated.

Comment: It did work with the missing `/`. Now what if my file is not in the same folder. Should I use `__FILE__` and remove the name of the file ?

Comment: You can use the realpath() to retrieve absolute filepaths out of realtive filepaths. I will write you an example in my answer.

Comment: `__FILE__` without filename is equal `__DIR__` :)

Normally I define and use my own constanst (e.g. `FILE_STORAGE_DIR`). And then work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use relative path to file. If it lies in the same folder as a PHP script, use `unlink(__DIR__ . '/' . $filename);`. In other cases set a full path to `unlink`.

Comment: Keep telling me my file doesn't exist

Comment: `file_exists` tells the same?

Comment: `file_exists` return `true`

Comment: Oh, gosh. Please give me full your code here )

Comment: Adding the missing `/` worked :)